# UndeliverableException thrown within a RxAndroidBle stream

Tags: rx-java2, rxandroidble

I have a misbehaving BLE device (temp sensor) that keeps throwing a `status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)` exception everytime i try to connect to the device. I'm not concerned about this exception as the device is faulty.

However, I keep getting notified that i've not handled the error correctly by rxjava2 when using RxAndroidBle(1.9.1); see here;

**This is my code.**

```
 rxBleClient
                .getBleDevice(macAddress)
                .establishConnection(false)
                .flatMapSingle { it.readRssi() }
                .subscribe({ "test1:Success" }, { "test1:error" })
```

**and the Error**

```
   I/RxBle#GattCallback: MAC='E9:CF:8A:D0:01:19'  onConnectionStateChange(), status=8, value=0
D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: FINISHED ConnectOperation(147547253) in 10257 ms
D/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue: Connection operations queue to be terminated (MAC='E9:CF:8A:D0:01:19')
    com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from MAC='E9:CF:8A:D0:01:19' with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback$2.onConnectionStateChange(RxBleGattCallback.java:77)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1$4.run(BluetoothGatt.java:249)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.runOrQueueCallback(BluetoothGatt.java:725)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:244)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
D/BleDeviceManagerNew$observeRssiTest: test1:error
E/plication$setupApp: Terminal Exception From RXJAVA was Not handled correctly
    io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from MAC='E9:CF:8A:D0:01:19' with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onError(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:67)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:63)
```

I'm not sure what else I should do - i've  implemented a 'catch all' solution but don't like this approach;

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { e -> Timber.e(e, "Terminal Exception From RXJAVA was Not handled correctly") }
```

but don't see that as a good solution as expected that i should be-able to handle exception on the steam. Any suggestions of where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. The library has a flaw that does not allow to achieve your desired behaviour. More on the topic is on [this library's wiki page](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/wiki/FAQ:-UndeliverableException).

While it is possible to design an API that would not throw `UndeliverableException` it would need to have a separate error `Observable` or `Completable` for `BluetoothAdapter` turning off and a separate one for `RxBleConnection` disconnect. The user would be responsible to mix those into their chain appropriately.

Current API does not allow it.

Comment: Thanks @Dariusz - I can happily live with the workaround as referenced on the wiki but my fear was that it was me doing something incorrectly - your answer resolves this concern.